# What is the best chemical cleaning agent clean tough stains out of a microwave other than vinegar, baking soda and lemon juice?

Tags: cleaning, microwave

I have seen this question posted on here before but the answers are always always water, vinegar, baking soda, or lemon juice. I have tried all these methods and including boiling and steaming each one.

Despite it's flammability, I have also resorted to nail polish and no luck.

Any other suggestions? I'm a neat freak and prefer my kitchen looking clean.

Thank you

Comment: Please tell me you are considering *nail polish **remover***, not *nail polish*...

Comment: I take it you've already tried a nonstick-safe sponge/scrubber, and lots of elbow grease?

Comment: Yes I have tried elbow grease and semi-abrasive sponges.

Comment: Acetone is a bad idea. There are plastics which react badly to it. Try surfactants like formula 409: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_409

Answer (score 2):

Bar Keepers friend is a powdered cleaning agent that contains oxalic acid as its main active ingredient, along with abrasives. It's great for removing many kitchen stains, including the polymerized oils that get baked onto pots and stovetops.

Acetone (the nail polish remover you have been using) is highly flammable, and toxic, so should never be used anywhere near food.

Comment: Oxyclean also works if you can't get Bar Keepers Friend easily. I keep both handy, personally.

Answer (score 2):

Heat a reasonably damp, but not dripping / soaking, kitchen cloth in the microwave for a minute. The steam produced will soften most deposits and then a bit of elbow grease and it's done. Do on a daily basis or after each use and the interior, especially the roof, will remain clean.
Beware of the cloth when removing it! Use another to hold it as it will of course be at the temperature of steam.

Comment: If my microwave is ever really bad, I microwave a pint of water for 10-15 minutes.  It produces enough steam to loosen up everything.

Answer (score 1):

The cleaners you mentioned are generally safe to use and should have been able to remove normal food soil. It sounds like you have something that is particularly stubborn and/or has baked onto the oven over time.

The next thing to try would be ammonia, but be careful because it's caustic and noxious. An aerosol lye spray oven cleaner would be even more powerful, but also more hazardous, so use that only as a last resort.

***Take care to avoid skin contact with these cleaners, and don't breathe in their fumes!***

Once you've thoroughly cleaned your microwave, it will stay clean if you take care to cover food while cooking. When splatters do occur, they're much easier to remove if cleaned up immediately. Otherwise, the splattered food hardens and the stains get baked on.

Comment: Maybe try Bar Keepers Friend first? It's a lot less nasty than ammonia and seems to work on an awful lot of things in the kitchen.